# Docker-Compose Liquibase fails to connect to mysql database on first run

Tags: mysql, docker-compose, liquibase

I am using docker-compose to launch a development environment. Among the containers are the mysql container running the mysql database and the liquibase container. The liquibase container shuold apply all updates necessary to the mysql database. The database contents and schema are being kept in the mounted "my-db" volume, so schema and data persists across "docker-compose down" and "docker-compose up" commands.

The issue I have is on the first run of the "docker-compose up" command, the liquibase container fails to connect. This issue happens on first pull of the repo, and also on subsequent "docker-compose up" commands IF I use "docker-compose down **-v**". This indicates to me that the issue only happens when launching both the containers *and* the "my-db" volume at the same time, and that the db isn't ready to accept connections quickly enough.

I have tried using docker-compose healthcheck to make sure the liquibase container spins up after the mysql container, and although the healthcheck seems to be working, the liquibase container still fails on first run with new volume. I think this is because the healthcheck only connects to the server and doesn't actually check if it is ready to be connected to. If this is the case I would love some help in creating a more precise healthcheck for the mysql container.

Here is the relevant parts of the docker-compose.yaml:

```
  liquibase:
    image: liquibase/liquibase:latest
    volumes:
      - ./CBCDevDB/:/liquibase/changelog/
    environment:
      - INSTALL_MYSQL=true
    command: --defaultsFile=/liquibase/changelog/liquibase.dev.properties update
    networks:
      - lbdb
    depends_on:
      - database

  database:
    image: mysql:latest
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=db
      - MYSQL_USER=liquibase
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=liquibase
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=example
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    volumes:
      - my-db:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - lbdb
      - backend
    healthcheck:
      test:
        [
          "CMD",
          "mysqladmin",
          "-u $MYSQL_USER",
          "-p $MYSQL_PASSWORD",
          "ping",
          "-h",
          "localhost",
        ]
      start_period: 5s
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 10

volumes:
  my-db:

networks:
  lbdb: {}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own problem,
there were two issues causing this. Firstly, I needed to be connected to the internet for the liquibase container to download the connector thing to connect to mysql database.

Secondly, I needed to set the depends on property of the liquibase container to require that the database is healthy before connecting. I still get some errors but at least they are rare now. I would say it works 80% of the time now, which is better than 0.